# Intel VTune Installer doesn't launch properly on my Windows 11 machine

Tags: profiler, windows-11, intel-vtune, intel-oneapi

[image: Message before window quits]

I'm trying to install VTune on my machine (I have windows 11 (x64), 8GB of RAM with Intel I7), however the installer gives me this message (see image attached) and when I click continue, the window pops out and quits and so it doesn't get installed properly.

I have Visual studio 2022 with Microsoft* Visual Studio* C/C++ Compiler installed.
I tried installing the Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit instead but the same problem.

I checked the requirements and it seems that I have everything right so why isn't it installed properly?

Answer (score 2):

If your vs2022 version is 17.1 then I have the same system configuration and problem as you. This link really helps https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Registration/BaseKit-oneAPI-installer-crashes-Windows-10/m-p/1360991

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you can refer the link given by bear2s and you can also refer the following link
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Registration/VTune-Installation-Fails-Windows-11-Visual-Studio-2022-17-1-0/m-p/1362923/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEtaWkNJQ0RLNzgySlFTfDEzNjI5MjN8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M2468

Answer (score 0):

I get the same question on windows 10.
I quit installation in the middle to install visual studio first.
But after visual studio installed, the vtune installer quits without any message when I try to install vtune.
Reboot the computer does not helping.

Comment: I uninstalled visual studio and everything I installed that day. It works now.